# Send 404 Status Code on www.example.com

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 404

Does anyone know if it's at all possible (preferably with *.htaccess*), to send a 404 error code and page when visiting `http://www.example.com` but have `http://example.com` working just fine?

I want to 404 the entire `www` website including the homepage.

Comment: Why would you want to do that when you can just as easily redirect which is better for SEO and usability?

Comment: it is possible with htaccess, but as mentioned, unless you want to punish the user, it's better to just redirect.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's generally not a good idea, just wanting to run this as a test that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.domain.com [nocase]

    RedirectMatch 404 ^(.*)`

Answer (score -2):

It makes no sense to run a HTTP server on a (v)-host if every request will result in a 404. Why not just fix your DNS setup so that the www subdomain isn't matched by any records? That way, the www variant won't even resolve.